# passing \n into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, parameters, newline

I have a javascript function that takes in a parameter that is given by a php session.

This works well except when the value is from a text area that contains a newline character.
I guess it appears as if I'm passing in a parameter and then the newline indicates I have stopped or something like that. Please advise on how to fix this. I tried using nl2br but it gives a similar error as passing in `<br />` is making it think that I forgot to close off the parameter delimiter

```
addElement('textarea', 'contact_address', 'Address:',   '<?=isset($_SESSION['contact_address']) ? $_SESSION['contact_address'] : "" ?>');
```

I am guessing I need to get rid of the newline character but I'm not sure of the best way to go about this so that the textarea value maintains its original format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)

```
addElement('textarea', 'contact_address', 'Address:',
   <?=json_encode(isset($_SESSION['contact_address']) ? $_SESSION['contact_address'] : "" ?>);
```

Comment: I added a regular expression to remove the escaping of characters such as '. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
addElement('textarea', 'contact_address', 'Address:',   '<?=isset($_SESSION['contact_address']) ? trim($_SESSION['contact_address']) : "" ?>');
```